# URL shorteners or redirectors whose target links can be changed after it was made

Tags: url, url-shortening

Are there any URL shorteners or redirectors whose target links can be changed by its creator after it was made?

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have a look at this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/url-shorteners-or-redirectors-whose-target-links-can-be-changed-after-it-was-mad